# Haskell Syntax Highlighting for code-server

Tags: haskell, xcode-server

I want to use the https://github.com/cdr/code-server for Haskell development. But there is one problem with Haskell Syntax Highlighting. Code-server does not support language extensions (https://github.com/JustusAdam/language-haskell/).
I don't need special tools for Haskell development. I just want to have syntax highlighting for .hs anf .cabal files.
Maybe there is some way to add syntax highlighting for Haskell?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me with code-server 3.9.0 and manually installing the extension via VSIX. (I built the extension from GitHub)

If you want to request this extension in the code-server marketplace, you can file an issue. code-server will soon be integrated with the open-vsx marketplace, so it could be supported there: https://github.com/cdr/code-server/pull/2659

[picture: code-server with Haskell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKdre.jpg)